# Colour change acid-base titration

Tags: titration

I titrated orange juice with NaOH. I used no indicator, but at around the point of inflection, the juice changed colour to a more mustard-ish colour. What is the reason for this colour change?

Comment: Many (arguably, _most_) natural dyes have some indicator properties.

Comment: E.G. tea (turns yellow with lemon) and particularly red cabbage. See https://www.thoughtco.com/edible-ph-indicators-color-chart-603655 for a convenient list of edible pH indicators. Also see *anthocyanin*.